# audit feature of the Worklight Server Administration console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, audit, worklight-console

Anybody knows about audit feature of the Worklight Server 6.2 Administration console?
What are the audit details stored by worklight server?
Where is it stored?
How long the data will be stored?
How to purge these data?
Again could not find any relevant information on info center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is about the Audit log available to download at the footer in Worklight Console.

> What are the audit details stored by Worklight Server?

The audit log contains every action done in the Worklight console and that was written to the database. This includes: the action timestamp, action type, action status, user role, artifact type.

> Where is it stored?

In the Worklight Server database.

By default, the Worklight Development Server uses a file-based database (HSQL). You cannot access this file while the server is running (when not running, the file can be accessed by some tools. You can google for them; not especially recommended to touch it).

> How long the data will be stored?

The data is stored for as long as the database is not cleared.

> How to purge these data?

Manually delete the your_workspace\WorklightServerConfig folder.

[From the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/admin/r_logging_and_monitoring_mechanisms.html):

```
Audit log for administration operations
Worklight Console stores an audit log for login, logout, and for all administration operations, such as deploying apps or adapters or locking apps. 
The audit log can be disabled by setting the JNDI property ibm.worklight.admin.audit on the web application of the Worklight Administration service (worklightadmin.war) to false.

When the audit log is enabled, you can download it from Worklight Console by clicking the Audit log link in the footer of the page.
```

Comment: I understand that trace.log can be enabled using application server. But I was looking for audit feature available for worklight server. This is the property to turn on or off the audit for worklight "ibm.worklight.admin.audit" and if you log in to worklight console and see at the footer you will see audit log and activity log. These logs can be downloaded from the link provided in the footer. Another option to download these log is to use rest service of Worklight service and the url is "management-api/1.0/audit".

Comment: When you ask a question, please do try to actually mention what you're talking about... now I understand you. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Thanks for the info. :) I did mention audit log for worklight administration **console**. Sorry, if It was not clear enough. I guess I should have include more information in my question, Thanks anyway.